# What type of ultrasonic transducers are used in medical ultrasound devices?

Tags: identification, ultrasound, transducer, medical

When I search on DigiKey for ultrasonic transducers, all I get back is the circular transducers that are sold for the various DIY projects. i.e. the picture below:

[image]

However, the "medical" ultrasound devices have a wand, that houses an array of what seems like a linear ultrasound transducers. i.e. the picture below:

[image]

Question is, what is the correct term to name (search for) the rectangular shape vs the circular shape transducers?

Comment: "Linear transducer." I've worked with such wands... 128 elements, Operating frequency something like 9MHz. If you could see inside the cable, there are 128 foil-shielded micro co-ax cables inside, each about 3 human hairs wide.

Comment: @rdtsc They work as a phased array, right?

Comment: @DKNguyen they can be phased or out of phase, linear or curved. The Linear or curve physical design is created in order design the "array" or "fan " view of returned image. (This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s23_d-qeEn4&t=747s [at 7:47] explains this very well). From my understanding, the phasing is done in order to overcome depth and material issues.

Comment: @rdtsc would you know where to get these Linear Transducers? I was wondering if I can just get the element itself, and design the rest?

Comment: I'm not seeing any offerings. They must all be custom-made.

Answer (score 3):

US transducers use an array of piezo-electric ceramics mechanically tuned to desired frequencies.  You can usually buy what you're looking for, or order custom parts, at places like https://piezotechnologies.com/

Note that the handle you're looking at is probably many individual crystals in an array, not a single element.  The US device often sends out a complete wavefront.